# Upgrade cyrus and split mailboxes

Tags: migration, mailbox, cyrus

I'm trying to upgrade a Cyrus IMAP server from 2.2.12 to 2.4.12/13.

Right know I'm looking for a good guide to do it, as my actual version is an old release. I guess it will not just be upgrade the version or install the new one and import the configuration, am I wrong? I assume I will need to migrate the database information, but do not know how to go about doing so.

Our main and unique Cyrus server is managing more than 10000 users and their corresponding mailboxes. With the new migration we want to split this main server into smaller servers to split the mailboxes by client. How can export I just a few mailboxes from Cyrus 2.2.12? I want to export the mailboxes selectively.

I found "Mailsync" tools, but it does not look like it can be selective with mailbox. Is there any way to migrate to the new version of Cyrus properly?

Answer (score 3):

(About eight years ago I migrated more than 50 000 user accounts from an old mail server (running uw-imapd) to a new server 'farm' consisting three servers and running Cyrus. At that time I used my l337 Perl skills for creating a migration script which would login to old server and copy the mails the new server over IMAP one user account at a time. An OpenLDAP server + `Perdition` was in front of this thing deciding where a user should be forwarded (to old server or to new server). The operation was done on-line without any downtime. This is going off-topic, so I'll continue with my reply.)

A word of warning: the job you are going to do can be a bit tedious and typing a short enough reply for you is not easy, either. :-) Here are some points for you to consider.

You have some work to do. Upgrading Cyrus itself is not that impossible, but splitting the users from one server to multiple servers at the same time requires planning. Just copying everything from the old server to new does not work, since BerkeleyDB/skiplist format has been changed in the middle and the old data files are not usable out of the box.

When it comes to user/mailbox list, it's better to use `ctl_mboxlist -d` switch to dump the user/mailbox information at the old server to a text file, and then `ctl_mboxlist -u` to load the contents to the new server. This is the case if you only would upgrade Cyrus and at the same time moved to a more powerful, yet only single server. The mailboxes can be copied over with `rsync`, followed by `reconstruct -rfx user/*` command in Cyrus.

If you want to do the split at the same time, you might want to try if `xfermailbox` command in `cyradm` nowadays actually lets you move mailboxes from one server to another. If it does, you can just create a script which calls `xfermailbox` 10 000 times and moves your user accounts wherever you want.

Another tip: You probably need `reconstruct -rfx user/someaccount` command if you find that after migration some user cannot find the mail folders / mails.

All fine and dandy until this, but have you considered the following:

- If you are going to split the users among multiple servers, do you have something like `Perdition` or `Cyrus Murder` taking care of redirecting POP/IMAP logins to correct mail server?
- If splitting, do you have OpenLDAP or some other centralized authentication  / user management in place?
- If splitting, have you configured your Postfix or whatever SMTP server to figure out where the user account actually is?
- Do you currently have performance problems? 10 000 user accounts is not very much and unless you truly have some serious reasons for splitting the user accounts across multiple servers, you should carefully reconsider this. A centralized storage of some kind + two semi-powerful servers configured in active/passive failover mode might be more wise and more simple in terms of system administration. Of course, having multiple smaller servers with local disks might help to spread I/O load, but Cyrus says 'Thank you' if you give it enough RAM and I/O should not be a real problem.
- If the reason for your decision to split the load to across multiple servers is due performance problems, please double-check if your Cyrus is using BerkeleyDB or Skiplist for `mailboxes.db` etc. BerkeleyDB without a well-tuned `DB_CONFIG` might easily kill the performance and/or lead to deadlocks. Skiplist is more worry-free. Also the POP3 implementation in Cyrus is very entropy hungry and if your server doesn't have a hardware based random number generator, the logins might be VERY slow without `rngd` daemon, or Cyrus configured to use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random` for randomness.

I hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: i can not use neither xfermailbox or ctl_mboxlist -u to import mailbox. The first option 'xfermailbox user.foo 192.168.xx.xx' return me "xfermailbox: Operation is not supported on mailbox", and the second one 'ctl_mboxlist -u < /root/export' return me "line 1: no partition found"

Comment: Thank you for `ctl_mboxlist -d` / `ctl_mboxlist -u` tip! `reconstruct -m` does not seem to be supported in most recent cyrus 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You have given me nice clue to follow.

Anyway I will answer the ideas I should consider:

- We have perdition, but we are considering to keep perdition or change to nginx.
- We have LDAP
- Right now I'm not sure abaout this and I should check it and investigate
- Nowadays we have not performance problems, but we are growing and more clients are comming to our system. We though that maybe split by clients or groups of client should be a good option. It coulb be a tedious work from SysAdmin point of view but could be good for the bussines and SLA. Any other option will good received :)
- As I commented before, we have not preformance problems, in any case we are using BerkeleyDB

Anyway, right know I'm doing a scheme of what we should do to sucess in or migration, so I cannot try the commands you provide me.

I will come back when I check them.

Thanks a lot!